# How is this type of login called

Tags: authentication, terminology, nomenclature

Is there a common name for the type of login where you don't have a username and a password?

Example: website that sends a unique link and password to your e-mail, so that only you can access some information. However, you don't ever need to explicitly enter a username.

Answer (score 1):

That would fall under token-based authentication. With such links, those tokens (the unique id in the link) will usually expire after being used once. However, the same scheme is also in use when using APIs, where a user has an API token that can be used to access the API as the user. This solves the issue of having to send the password over the wire every time.

Comment: What if the unique id doesn't expire? Would you call it a token? And note that a password is provided. What isn't is a username

Comment: In that case, the unique id serves as your "username". It's something unique that identifies you and just you. The only risk in that case is, that others would be able to use the link as well if they should gain access to the mail.

Comment: Never had thought about that, but it does, indeed.